# Can't get onupgradeneeded to be called, no matter how many times I change the version number

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm trying to create an IndexedDb, and for some reason cannot get onupgradeneeded to be called, which means I can't create my object store. Any insight would be very helpful, here's the code I'm using:

```
    const request = window.indexedDB.open('OriginInvestmentsFrontEnd', 1);
    request.onerror = (event) => {
      console.log('error: ', event);
    };
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      console.log('success: ', event);
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
      console.log('onupgradeneeded: ', event);
      const db = event.target.result;
      db.createObjectStore('front-end-state');
    };
```

I have tried using version 1, 2, 3, 4 and 10 and 11 (none of these versions had been created previously.) No matter what I try, the onupgardeneeded method is never called, I only ever get the onsuccess method. What am I doing wrong here? From my understanding, a version change should trigger onupgradeneeded, but it doesn't?

Comment: if you open up dev tools, what is the current version? or print out the version property in the onsuccess event

Comment: The version always matches up with whatever version I’ve assigned it, which is even weirder. It’ll change versions without ever firing off an onupgradeneeded event....

Comment: Your code looks correct, so there's something non-obvious going on. Do you have another connection to the database which is preventing the upgrade (watch for `onblocked`) - the success event would be delayed as well but perhaps that's not obvious in your testing. Or perhaps a debugger with breakpoints, which is attaching the onupgradeneeded handler after the event fires?

Comment: same thing is happening with me also , did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue I was changing version to call onupgradeneeded but it was not getting called
But after researching I got one solution
**In my case connection was not getting close and that's why it was not triggering onupgradeneeded and instead it was trigeering `request.onblocked`**
**so close the connection in `request.onblocked` as well**

```
const request = window.indexedDB.open('OriginInvestmentsFrontEnd', 1);
db.onblocked = (event) => {
  console.log('blocked ...', event); // in my case this was triggering 
  (event.target as any).result.close(); // so close the connection and it worked
};
request.onerror = (event) => {
  console.log('error: ', event);
  (event.target as any).result.close(); // Close the connection
};
request.onsuccess = (event) => {
  console.log('success: ', event);
  (event.target as any).result.close(); // Close the connection
};

request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
  console.log('onupgradeneeded: ', event);
  const db = event.target.result;
  db.createObjectStore('front-end-state');
};
```